# How to shuffle listview position?

Tags: android

At present when user click on any index listview item marked as checked its working fine.

**Requirement:**
But now i want to show all checked index of listview on top and all unchecked at bottom,Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Using class to checked the listview position using sharepreferance, given below:

```
public class ColorSessionManager {

public static ArrayList<Boolean> listBoolTrain = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

private int giftRemaining;

private SharedPreferences prefs;

// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

public ColorSessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;

    prefs = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);

    editor = prefs.edit();
}

public void setNumberOfGits(int numberOfGifts) {
    editor.putInt("numberOfGifts", numberOfGifts);

    editor.commit();
}

public int getNumberOfGits() {
    int nog = prefs.getInt("numberOfGifts", -5);

    return nog;
}

public void initializerBooleans(int arraySiz) {
    int arraySize = prefs.getInt("arraySize", 10);

    for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {
        editor.putBoolean("Bool" + x, false);

        editor.commit();
    }
}

public void setItemVisited(int x) {
    editor.putBoolean("Bool" + x, true);

    editor.commit();
}

public boolean isItemVisited(int x) {
    return prefs.getBoolean("Bool" + x, false);
}

public int getUnVisitedItemCount() {
    int count = 0;

    int arraySize = prefs.getInt("arraySize", 10);

    for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++)// listBoolTrain.size(); x++)
    {
        boolean bol = prefs.getBoolean("Bool" + x, false);

        if (!bol) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public void remainingGift() {
}

public void setFirstRun(boolean status) {
    editor.putBoolean("firstrun", status);

    editor.commit();
}

public boolean getFirstRun() {
    return prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true);
}

public void removeAllPreferences() {
    prefs.edit().clear().commit();
}

public void removeKey(String keyName) {
    prefs.edit().remove(keyName).commit();
}

public void showAll() {
    Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": "
                + entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}

public void setArraySize(int boolSize) {
    editor.putInt("arraySize", boolSize);

    editor.commit();

    initializerBooleans(boolSize);
}

public int getArraySize() {
    return prefs.getInt("arraySize", -1);
}

public boolean ItemVisited(int position) {
    return prefs.getBoolean("Bool" + position, false);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listview, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listview, view, position, id);
        listview.setItemChecked(position, true); 

}
```

Select checked and unchecked items

```
final SparseBooleanArray checked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i=0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
            if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                 .....
            } else {
                 .....
            }
}
```